# compare textbox value C#

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

So I have 3 textboxes that I sum up and then compare to my 4th textbox and the value has to be less than the value in 4th textbox. I got it working but I want to be able to leave for example 1 of 3 textboxes empty. Here is my code:

Answer (score 1):

You can use double.TryParse, which will not through an exception, and will just leave the out variable untouched, eg:

```
double d1 = 0;
double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out d1);
// Repeat twice more

totalVal = d1 + d2 + d3;
```

Comment: You don't need to initialize the double passed as out to TryParse. _out_ means that the called method is guaranteed to initialize it.

Comment: @Steve - you are correct if using C# 7.0 or greater.  It was originally scheduled for C# 6.0 but MS pushed it to 7.0.  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
double a=0;
double b=0;
double c=0;

double.TryParse(textBox1.Text.Trim(), out a);
double.TryParse(textBox2.Text.Trim(), out b);
double.TryParse(textBox3.Text.Trim(), out c);
double totalVal = a+b+c;
```